# Replacement rules which for elements of a vector which meet conditions

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, conditional

I'm trying to create a function which will replace elements of a list with their values modulo 1, i.e. `Mod[x,1]`, but only if `Abs[x]>1`. So, for example, the function would yield:

```
f[{-1.5, -1, 0, 1}] = {.5, -1, 0, 1}
```

I'm trying to do this in an elegant way. For example, I have a function for a related purpose:

```
C1[v_] := v /. _?Negative -> 0;
```

This replaces negative elements of a list with 0, and it's very clean.

I'd like to do something similar. My efforts so far have included breaking it into two functions:

```
CLim[x_] := Mod[x, 1] /; Abs[x] > 1;

C2[v_] := CQubitLim /@ v;
```

But then, when I apply `C2` to a list, it only seems to apply on some elements, for example

```
C2[{1, 0, 1.5}] = {Clim[1], CLim[0], 0.5}
```

My other idea was to use a conditional rule

```
v :> Mod[v, 1] /; Abs[v] > 1
```

But this doesn't seem to evaluate when I put a vector through it.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Does `Function[x, If[Abs[x] > 1, Mod[x, 1], x]] /@ {-1.5, -1, 0, 1}` suit your needs?

Comment: @J.M. very elegant, compact solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the definition of `C2` for cases when `Abs[x]<=1`:

```
ClearAll[CLim, C2];
CLim[x_] := Mod[x, 1] /; Abs[x] > 1; 
CLim[x_] := x; 
C2[v_] := CLim /@ v


C2[{1, 0, -.5, 1.5}]
```

> ```
>  {1, 0, -0.5, 0.5}
> ```

Comment: I had no idea you could define functions twice like this, with different patterns. This is extremely useful!

Answer (score 2):

One way (perhaps not very elegant) is to use `SubsetMap` to map the modifying function only onto positions where the absolute value is greater than 1:

```
lst//SubsetMap[Mod[Abs[#],1]&, #, Pick[Range@Length@#,Sign[Abs[#]-1],1]]&
```

> {0.5, -1, 0, 1}

Answer (score 0):

```
C2 = # /. x_ /; Abs[x] > 1 :> Mod[x, 1] &;

C2[{1, 0, -.5, 1.5}]
```

{1, 0, -0.5, 0.5}